# Using glMapBufferRange to read data to a buffer

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I want to use `glMapBufferRange` to read out data. The way I use it is the following:

```cpp
bindBuffer(vboIdx);
void *ptr = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, size, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);
int err = glGetError();
assert(ptr);
memcpy(dst, ptr, size);
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
unbindBuffer();
```

However, `ptr` seems to be `NULL`. As stated in the documentation here: *[khronos - `glMapBufferRange`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml)*; the function returns `NULL` if an error occurs. Therefore, I checked for the error by using `glGetError()`. But the error I get is `0`, which is the same as `GL_NO_ERROR`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: But do you have accessible data there on that buffer? What does your `bindBuffer` do? Note that "the function returns NULL if an error occurred" does not mean "error occurs when function returns NULL". NULL may still be valid even if no error is reported.

Comment: " Note that "the function returns NULL if an error occurred" does not mean "error occurs when function returns NULL". " I also thought about that, but in the end ptr should be pointing to an address where I can copy the data from, so NULL seems to be definitely wrong then. The bindBuffer fct looks the follwing:
`assert(vboIdx < numVBOs);   
    glBindVertexArray(vao);  
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbos[vboIdx]);`

Comment: I know this may sound like one of those "is it plugged into electricity" question but... Do you have a valid set openGL context at the time you are calling this? Removing context seems to produce the issue you describe. Note that switching to a different thread than the one you draw on may be enough. Contexts should be per-thread. Also could you provide a code that calls `glBufferData`?

Comment: Well I would give you more detailed information but the code you provided kind-of doesn't completely look like a usual Android openGL API. Anyway, in most cases you will have a context. It might be created by some higher level component like surface view. When no context is present each of your call to "gl" functions will do nothing, return 0, null... Which is also your result. A context is present if it is set as  current on given thread. On android you should always be able to get it via `EGLContext.eglGetCurrentContext()`.

Comment: Oh you're right I actually set a context (see my updated post below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I haven't heard about the OpenGL context so far (just read about it), I started writing my code based on [android's sensor graph sample project](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/master/sensor-graph).

To answer your question, I haven't had a problem so far and I guess yes, but I'm not 100% sure. Before requesting a data readout I write data to the buffer:

```cpp
if(dataSize == 0) {
    return;
}

 bindBuffer(vboIdx);
 if(dataSize > vertexBufSize[vboIdx] - offset) {
     glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataSize, data, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
     vertexBufSize[vboIdx] = dataSize;
 }

 void *ptr = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, dataSize, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT);
 int err = glGetError();
 assert(ptr);

 if(data != nullptr) {
     memcpy(ptr, data, dataSize);
 }

 glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
     unbindBuffer();
```

This is where I call `glBufferData()`

Java Side:

```java
mView = (GLSurfaceView) frameLayout.findViewById(R.id.plot_view);
mView.setEGLContextClientVersion(3);
mView.setEGLConfigChooser(true);
if(LOG) Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView(): get ID: " + mView.getId());

isStreaming = true;
mView.setRenderer(new GLSurfaceView.Renderer() {
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
  mLiveViewJNI.surfaceCreated();
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
  mLiveViewJNI.surfaceChanged(width, height);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
  mLiveViewJNI.drawFrame();
}

});
```

[@Matic Oblak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318143/using-glmapbufferrange-to-read-data-to-a-buffer#comment102997817_58318143) was right, the context was actually the problem. As long as I only touched the buffers via JNI within `onSurfaceCreated`, `onSurfaceChanged` or `onDrawFrame` everything was fine.

But as soon as I tried to access them outside for instance via `mLiveViewJNI.dummyCall` I ran into that problem and everything returned `0` or `NULL`.